# Send RAW video via UDP using GStreamer

Tags: udp, gstreamer

I'm trying to use `gst-launch-1.0` to send RAW video data from an `.avi` file through UDP from one computer on my network to another, so I can finally save it as a `.y4m` file. The pipeline on the source computer returns no errors, but the pipeline on the sink computer does.

Here's the pipeline I used for the source computer:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e filesrc location=input.avi ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! rtpvrawpay ! \
udpsink host=192.168.1.167 port=7001
```

For the sink computer (`192.168.1.167`), I used:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e udpsrc uri=udp://0.0.0.0 port=7001 ! \
"application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)RAW,\
sampling=(string)YCbCr-4:2:0,depth=(string)8,width=(string)1280,height=(string)720,\
colorimetry=(string)SMPTE240M,payload=(int)96,ssrc=(uint)878094790,\
timestamp-offset=(uint)1636480077,seqnum-offset=(uint)25415,a-framerate=(string)60,\
timestamp=(uint)1636480077,seqnum=(uint)25515" ! \
rtpvrawdepay ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,framerate=60/1,format=I420 ! filesink location=output.y4m
```

This pipeline returns the error:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../gstreamer/subprojects/gstreamer/libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3132): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
```

I've got the caps for `application/x-rtp` from the verbose output of `gst-launch-1.0` on the source computer. I've tried the caps with and without the `{ssrc, timestamp-offset, seqnum-offset, timestamp, seqnum}` parameters, since I've noticed these change with every run, but it still didn't work.

What's more is that a similar pipeline system to send H.264 video over UDP works just fine; I leave the source and sink pipelines below as an example:

###### Source

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e filesrc location=input.avi ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! \
x264enc key-int-max=30 ! h264parse config-interval=-1 ! rtph264pay ! \
udpsink host=192.168.1.167 port=7001
```

###### Sink

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc uri=udp://0.0.0.0 port=7001 ! \
application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! \
rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! queue ! autovideosink sync=false
```

This combination displays the video on screen without any issues.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First be sure that your input.avi source has H264 video (decodebin would manage other codecs but your pipeline wouldn't).

```
gst-discoverer-1.0 input.avi
```

You would try adding avidemux between filesrc and h264parse.

If it doesn't help, a possible cause could be that RAW video may result in much bigger packets than H264 compressed video.

You may try increasing kernel socket max buffer size (you would need root priviledges on sender and receiver to do that):

```
# Increase max kernel socket buffer size to 1M or more on receiver side with:
sudo sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=1000000

# Then use property buffer-size of udpsrc such as:
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc uri=udp://0.0.0.0 port=7001 buffer-size=1000000 ! 'application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=RAW,sampling=YCbCr-4:2:0, depth=(string)8, width=(string)1280, height=(string)720,colorimetry=(string)SMPTE240M,payload=(int)96,a-framerate=(string)60' ! rtpvrawdepay ! videorate ! y4menc ! queue ! filesink location=output.y4m -e
```

```
# Increase max kernel socket buffer size to 1M or more on sender side with:
sudo sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=1000000

# and use buffer-size property of udpsink as well:
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=input.avi ! avidemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! rtpvrawpay ! 'application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, encoding-name=(string)RAW' ! udpsink host=192.168.1.167 port=7001 buffer-size=1000000
```

Comment: played around a bit and realised that the problem was with the `videoconvert` element in the sink pipeline, since it was probably trying to convert framerate as well (the original video is 200fps and I needed 60fps); turns out I should use `videorate` instread
I've tried your solution and it works, although I didn't have to change muxing or buffer size at all - thank you though!

Comment: Yes, at first in my case I didn't needed that, but after some (untracked) trials, I saw the framerate set to 0/1 so I added videorate and it worked out. Glad to see it helped, though you may investigate and further share.